# SQL Server 2008 duplication of rows and averages

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the average and last date row from a table that has duplications of rows for the same ID, for example:

```
Table:
ID  VisitID     Date            Value
1   1       10-10-2001      1
2   1       10-11-2001      1
1   2       10-11-2001      3
OUT PUT
Table:
ID  VisitID     Date                Value
1   1       10-11-2001 ***(max date)***     2  (***total of the two date / number of rows)***
2   1       10-11-2001          1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID 
,VisitID = MIN(VisitID)
,Date = MAX(Date)
,Value= COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
```

is what I think you want, unless I'm missing the question.

Comment: I think he's looking for the average of values (see my answer)

Comment: It worked well, I just had to change COUNT(*) to AVG(Value).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, MIN(VisitID) as VisitID, Date, AVG(Value) as Value
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID, Date
```

Comment: yep, but he's also looking for the MAX date :)   If you put both our answers together, he'll have a complete one.